# Ocaml : exception Graphics.Graphic_failure("Xlib error: BadPixmap (invalid Pixmap parameter)")

Tags: ocaml

I've a problem with a little function in caml.
Here my function :

```
let show img = 
  let h = height img in 
  let w = width img in
  open_graph (" "^string_of_int w^"x"^string_of_int h);
  set_window_title "Seam Carving";
  draw img;
  if Graphics.key_pressed() then 
    match Graphics.read_key() with
      | 'q' -> close_graph()
      | _ -> ()
;;
```

When I clicked on the button 'q', I've this error : 
`Fatal error: exception Graphics.Graphic_failure("Xlib error: BadPixmap (invalid Pixmap parameter)")` or segmentation fault.

Someone can to explain me the reason of a such error ? Thanks :)

Comment: You should try to provide a minimal compilable program exposing the issue you want to get explanation for.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no reply to your question, as there is not enough information in it.

In general, if you experience a Segmentation Fault with OCaml, it is a MAJOR BUG, so you should fill a bug report on [OCaml bug tracker](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis), and upload a program reproducing the error.